# Recuperando FindControl do repeater pai no evento do repeater filho

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Estou com dificuldade para conseguir pegar um campo do meu repeater pai no click do meu linkbutton que esta dentro de outr repeater (filho).

Meu repeater pai contem o código do relatório e demais informações e meu repeater filho contem as datas desse relatório. Quando o usuário clicar em uma determinada data eu preciso pegar esse código do pai e tbem pegar a data para assim fazer o processo. Mas não estou conseguindo fazer nem um e nem outro.

Segue meu html:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" OnItemDataBound="rptRelatorioFavoritos_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
    <table>
        <tr class="titulo">
            <th colspan="4">Favoritos</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th width="5%" class="td_titulo">Relatório</th>
            <th width="10%" class="td_titulo">Assunto</th>
            <th width="20%" class="td_titulo">Descrição</th>
            <th width="25%" class="td_titulo">Clique na Data Desejada</th>
        </tr>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr class="tr_branco">
        <td class="td_branco">
            <asp:ImageButton CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CodRelatorio")%>' ID="imgbFavorito" ImageUrl="~/Content/imgs/BookDel.gif" OnCommand="imgbFavorito_Command" runat="server" ToolTip="Remover do seus favoritos?" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblCodRelatorio" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CodRelatorio")%>' />
        </td>
        <td class="td_branco">
            <asp:Label ID="lblAssunto" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AssuntoRelatorio")%>'></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td class="td_branco">
            <asp:Label ID="lblDescricao" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DescricaoRelatorio")%>'></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td class="td_branco">
            <asp:Label ID="lblLocal" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LojaRelatorio")%>'></asp:Label>

            <asp:Repeater ID="rptRelFilho" OnItemDataBound="rptRelFilho_OnItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptRelFilho_OnItemCommand" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lkbDataRelatorio" runat="server"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DataRelatorio")%></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lkbDataRelatorio02" runat="server">...</asp:LinkButton>
        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
    </table>
</FooterTemplate>
```

Meu .cs esta assim:

```
protected void rptRelFilho_OnItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        var itensPai = e.Item.Parent.Parent;
        var lblCodRel = (Label)itensPai.FindControl("CodRelatorio");


        var link = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("DataRelatorio");
        string v = link.Text;


    }
```

Segue a imagem do relatório para vcs terem uma noção do que eu estou tentando fazer. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

pelo que entendi a questão toda é capturar o valor de um controle fora do repeater filho mas dentro do repeater pai? Correto?

Veja o exemplo que construí seguindo essa ideia:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptPai" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptPai_ItemDataBound">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <th>Código</th>
                    <th>Descrição</th>
                    <th>Clique na data desejada</th>
                </thead>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%# Eval("Codigo") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Descricao") %></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:HiddenField id="hdfCodigoRelatorio" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Codigo") %>'/>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="rptFilho" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptFilho_ItemCommand">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lkbDataRelatorio" runat="server">
                                <%# this.GetDataItem().ToString() %>
                            </asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Observe que logo antes do repeater filho, chamado de rptFilho, coloquei um HiddenField que recebe o código do relatório daquela linha. É esse controle que vou acessar para pegar o código:

```
    protected void rptPai_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || args.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Repeater childRepeater = (Repeater)args.Item.FindControl("rptFilho");
            HiddenField hdfCodigoRelatorioPai = (HiddenField)args.Item.FindControl("hdfCodigoRelatorio");

            childRepeater.DataSource = CarregarDatas(Convert.ToInt32(hdfCodigoRelatorioPai.Value));
            childRepeater.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

No ItemDataBound do repeater pai eu pego o código e uso para preencher as datas do repeater filho. Ao clicar em uma das datas do rptFilho, o evento ItemCommand é chamado:

```
    protected void rptFilho_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        var itensPai = e.Item.Parent.Parent;
        HiddenField hdfCodigoRelatorioPai = (HiddenField)itensPai.FindControl("hdfCodigoRelatorio");

    }
```

Veja acima que a captura dos itens do Pai é igual a forma como vocês estava fazendo, e basta dar um findControl para trazer o controle que deseja. Fiz um teste e o valor do código do relatório é retornado sem problemas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta é apenas uma forma de fazer, no ItemDataBound do repeater pai você ja poderia passar o código do relatório e jogar isso para o repeater filho também.

Espero ter sido claro. Qualquer dúvida fala aí. :)